# How to extract exact information by span class using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, pycharm

This is my code and output for my price monitoring code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="result_0_name").get_text()
price = soup.find("span", class_ = "normal_price")
#converted_price = price[0:3]

print(price.get_text())
print(title.strip())
```

the output is as follows

```
Starting at:
$0.70 USD
$0.67 USD

Operation Broken Fang Case
```

and html of the page is as so

```
<span class="market_table_value normal_price">Starting at:<br/>
<span class="normal_price" data-currency="1" data-price="69">$0.69 USD</span>
<span class="sale_price">$0.66 USD</span>
</span>
```

as you can see there is no ID, so I cannot use that, I only wish to display the 'normal_price' and not the other data in that span. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the selection of the span more specific, for example use the fact, that it is an element inside an element:

```
soup.select_one('span > span.normal_price').get_text()
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''
<span class="market_table_value normal_price">
                    Starting at:<br/>
<span class="normal_price" data-currency="1" data-price="69">$0.69 USD</span>
<span class="sale_price">$0.66 USD</span>
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

price = soup.select_one('span > span.normal_price').get_text()

price
```

**Output**

```
$0.69 USD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ="""<span class="market_table_value normal_price">
                    Starting at:<br/>
<span class="normal_price" data-currency="1" data-price="69">$0.69 USD</span>
<span class="sale_price">$0.66 USD</span>
</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

using attribute
price = soup.select_one('span[data-currency="1"]').get_text()
exact attribute
price = soup.select_one('span[data-currency^="1"]').get_text()

print(price) #$0.69 USD
```

Comment: Yes, that works, I wasnt looking at it from outside a class attribute. Also, I'm just starting college and i'm quiet into coding, are there any guides you could refer me to which could help me understand different APIs.
Thanks so much for your help

Comment: You could follow beautifulsoup document https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Please Upvote,accept this/any Answer which is useful to you